# Cordova.JS in Visualforce Page running on force.com site for hybrid app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, cordova

i did the following steps. But cordova plugin for android doesnt seem to work for me in force.com site

Steps followed for Cordova

1.Cordova create appname. (cd appname)
2.cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
3.cordova platform add android

Steps followed in salesforce side:

1.Force.com site is created.
2.platforms -> android ->assets->www-> Zipped the following contents(cordova.js,cordova-plugin.js,plugin folder).
3.Static resource has been created with the above zip file.
3.Visualforce page is created with same code as found in (http://th3silverlining.com/2015/02/07/using-native-mobile-device-features-from-visualforce-with-phonegap/)

Changed the value from index.html to the force.com site url in config.xml.

Cordova build android Cordova emulate android . Android emulator is opened with my site in app.

But the plugin doesnt seem to work. when i click the outputLink, i am getting normal js alert only in my android emulator :(

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for JavaScript Errors? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#errors-and-warnings Would you be willing to share a link to your force.com site here?

Comment: Apologies for my delayed response :( 
No. i did not check in dev console as i am trying to run the app in my mobile.
my Force.com site link:
http://cloudyy-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/Cordova

Comment: If needed, i can even create a user credential for u in my org so that you can check it . Thanks  a lot for your help and your time.

Comment: @WesNolte Can you please help me .. its bit urgent as i am working on a project similar to this with deadline sep 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for the above question. 
The problem was cordova whitelist plugin did not allow my force.com site to access plugin. So finally i added the value "" in my config.xml and atlast i got a native dialog.

Thanks a lot wes for the blog and your help